# Determine type of filtering applied between two images

Tags: filters

I am not too familiar with DSP, and would be grateful for a pointer in the right direction.

Given two images A and B, is it possible to determine the filtering applied, and thereby apply it again to other candidate images?

For example, if you have an image of a triangle, and the second image is of that triangle rotated 90 degrees. Or the first image is a square, and the second image is a pentagon. Is it possible to determine the filter applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are  more looking at image (geometric) transformations than at filtering, at least in the traditional convolution sense. I will describe a few techniques and keywords to give you some starting points. In the case of the triangle, you might look for `rotations`, `scaling` (or `dilation`), `shifts`, perhaps `shearing`, that globally preserve the shape of the object, see for instance [2D Transformations](https://www.willamette.edu/~gorr/classes/GeneralGraphics/Transforms/transforms2d.htm) for examples and demos or [Transforming shapes](http://www2.saplinglearning.com/sites/default/files/SaplingLearning_Geom_Ch5.pdf).

There exists a large body of works in image processing, under the name  `RST` (rotation, scale, translation) transforms. One often talks about `similarity`, or [`rigid body` transformations](http://elonen.iki.fi/code/misc-notes/2d-rigid-fit/). If you add shear, you get the class of `affine` transforms.

Once you identify them, you can perform [`alignment` or `registration`of images](http://depts.washington.edu/bicg/documents/MII_registration10.pdf).

To identify them, you have mostly two main techniques:

- work directly on images, for instance with different transforms: to name a few: Fourier, Fourier-Mellin, scale, Radon, multiscale or wavelet decompositions. Those have some invariance with respect of the transformations studied.
- work on keypoints, a reduced quantity of features extracted from images ([SIFT, SURF, ORB, FREAK, BRISK, FAST](https://www.quora.com/Computer-Vision-There-are-several-kinds-of-detectors-and-descriptors-like-SIFT-SURF-FAST-BRIEF-ORB-BRISK-FREAK-I-wonder-are-they-all-eligible-for-real-time-applications-Which-is-the-best-or-better)), and then work on the resulting point cloud or point set.

As images are not perfectly transformed, as you have noise or occlusions, `non-rigid` transformations can be useful too, by allowing a non-constant transformation across the image. One of these techniques is [CDP (coherent point drift)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0905.2635.pdf).

For all of the above, many computer languages have implementation available, and they require some care and tuning, depending on the images.

The case of the square transformed into a pentagon is more complex. Due to the change in shape, I can see no unique, natural way to transform one into the other. So you have a huge problem of identification.

Last, Fourier is nice, but the division by a Fourier spectrum may yield a lot of "close-to-zero" division problem, that as well need to invest technically on the different methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Discrete Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform). One of it's interesting qualities is that convolution in the time domain is translated into multiplication in the frequency domain.

Applying a filter, represented by the function $h(t)$, on a signal\image $x(t)$ is equivalent, in fact, to convolving the two in the time domain. You can learn more about convolution [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution). We will denote the output of the operation $y(t)$, and it will be represented by $y(t)=x(t)*h(t)$. Note that $*$ in this context is a convolution operation.

If we will apply a Discrete Fourier transform $\mathcal F$ on both sides we get: 
$$\mathcal F[y(t)]=\mathcal F[x(t)*h(t)]=\mathcal F[x(t)]\cdot \mathcal F[h(t)]$$
Where the $\cdot$ denotes multiplication. This is again derived from the fact that convolution in the time domain is translated into multiplication in the frequency domain.

You can now use simple math to get:
$$\mathcal F[h(t)]=\frac{\mathcal F[y(t)]}{\mathcal F[x(t)]}$$
And hence:
$$h(t)=\mathcal F^{-1}\left[\frac{\mathcal F[y(t)]}{\mathcal F[x(t)]}\right]$$ where $\mathcal F^{-1}$ represent the inverse of DFT.

You can now use $h(t)$ for any new $x'(t)$ by applying:
$$y'(t)=x'(t)*h(t)\implies \mathcal F[y'(t)]=\mathcal F[x'(t)]\cdot \mathcal F[h(t)]$$

Sure DFT is a bit more complex on an image and you will have to learn how to apply it, but the principle is the same.

Comment: This is excellent, I'm going to try and implement this in Python later.

Comment: if we've determined h(t) as the rotation of a triangle, if I apply h(t) again, would it continue to rotate the triangle? Thus my question ultimately becomes: does h(t) represent a generalized transformation on any polygon?

Comment: $h(t)$ is the [Impulse response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_response) of a given system. It is used to describe the system and helps calculate the respond for any input signal. This is true for all systems. another way to find it will be to stimulate the system with an impulse. $y(t)=\delta (t)*h(t)=h(t) $ since $\mathcal F[\delta ]=1$.

Comment: I applied the convolution by multiplying in the frequency domain, but unfortunately, all I get back is the original image. h(t) didn't seem to have any effect.